# I cant detect my TP-LINK router after windows 10 update

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, router, wireless-router

Before Windows 10 update, I was able to detect my TP-LINK Router but after the updates, I can no longer see my TP-LINK Router in the Wi-Fi list. Everybody else in my network can detect this router except me. I tried to disable/enable its network adapter but it didnt worked! I tried to restart it several times but it didn't worked as well. I followed some tutorials in Google but it didn't worked!

Please help!

Comment: Uninstall the old driver and install the Windows 10 supported wifi driver for your machine.

Comment: Sorry to say that Im not an expert about computer, can you give a more comprehensive detail about how to do it?

Comment: Tell me your laptop model so that i can check and give you the correct driver for your wifi.

Comment: Could you please specify the exact model of your router (usually specified on the bottom or on the sides of the router) as well as model of your network adapter on your machine (can be found in ``Device manager`` as @vembutech shows below)?

Answer (score 0):

Go to device manager to update the old software.

Open run and type devmgmt.msc to open device manager, then right click your wifi driver and update it if update also din't work then uninstall it and install the correct driver.

Tell me your laptop model so that i can check and give you the correct driver for your wifi.

Get back if you need more information.

[image: Devicemanager]

Comment: I did what you said, but it says "The best driver software for your device is already installed." I still cannot detect my router.

Answer (score 0):

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3c50a750-4be3-4a23-8b2c-4e0fa28aba74/windows-10-anniversary-1607-thinks-i-am-not-connected-cannot-update-edge-and-store-do-not-work?forum=win10itpronetworking

It is NOT related to your driver. It is a Microsoft problem of identifying you router and by that define the Network Location (Which you can later set as Private or Public).

The procedure that works is strange, simple and works (except DLINK 6850 with some proprietary firmware):

1. Roll back to 1511: Settings/Update&Security/Recovery select "go back to an earlier build"
2. Re-install windows 1607 upgrade
3. Also check for an updated version of FW for your router.

This should correct the problem.
Why would rollback and re-upgrade work - we don't know. But the procedure works so far in every computer that had this problem.